# Graphical umount application

Tags: mount, gui, partitioning, deb, umount

Is there some application to graphically view which partitions are mounted and be able to unmount them from the GUI? Like on Windows -> My Computer -> Eject.

Comment: Most file browsers have that function.

Answer (score 0):

Download `Gparted`:

· From Ubuntu Software

· Run the command `sudo apt-get install gparted`

Answer (score 0):

That functionality is included in Nautilus by default.

Notice the red encircled area:

[image]

So you can see:

- My `137GB` volume is **not** mounted
- My `604GB` volume is mounted
- My `Stuff` volume is mounted

And to eject a mounted partition, you just have to click the eject icon.

Comment: Does this work for devices mounted using fstab? Isn't sudo required?

Comment: @OrganicMarble - Don't know.

Comment: I already knew that, buy I would like to know which device is mounted on each mount point, for example:

Comment: For example:
/dev/sda3 /media/username/Stuff